# I can't see hats in users' profiles on sites where I don't have an account

Tags: support, profile-page, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

I can't see any hats in user profiles on sites where I haven't joined yet. I have verified the same on most of the sites where I do not have an account.

For example: I'm not a member of [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com), when I check the hats in the [Winter Bash site's Leaderboard](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/leaderboard), I can see a user wearing a hat on their profile.

> [image: Leaderboard]

But when I navigate to their [Profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81360/omnomnomnom?tab=profile) and [Activity](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81360/omnomnomnom?tab=topactivity) tabs, I can't see any hats on their account.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Activity tab]

It this supposed to happen? Or is it a bug?
I didn't see any reference in the [FAQ](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/faq) page about this.